# Generic entity into a string always with a `d` at the end

Tags: java, generics, hql, jpql

I use a generic entitytype

```
Class<T> entityType;
```

and for a jqpl query I need the entityname Company/Depart etc.

I use the following statement:

```
+ entity.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

this returns almost the right string.

```
companyd / departmentd
       ^             ^
```

What's wrong with Java? why is there a `d`? and what method can help me to return the classname of the entity, but not full classified.

Comment: A snippet of the executed code would help.

Comment: Hi, i think i already found the problem. There is an exeption, that the class i want to use needs to be mapped.